# (discord py) I cant reffer to the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When i use `ctx.guild.roles` it says that i have no required ctx attribute *if message attribute is first* and message attribute is missing *if ctx is the first*.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message, ctx):
    if message.content == "!lighton":
        light = True
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Face")
        while light:
            await client.edit_role(server=server, role=role, colour=0xF7B0B0)
            asyncio.sleep(3)
            await client.edit_role(server=server, role=role, colour=0xD36D6D)
            asyncio.sleep(3)

    elif message.content == "!lightoff":
        light = False
```

I've tried to use `server = client.get_server(#server id#)`
The console says " 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_server' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```py
light = True

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global light
    if message.content == '@lighton':
        light = True
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = "Face")
        while light:
            await role.edit(colour = 0xF7B0B0)
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            await role.edit(colour = 0xD36D6D)
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
    elif message.content == '@lightoff':
        light = False
```

There were a few more errors in your code that I took the liberty of fixing.

Comment: I would've suggested an edit if the queue wasn't full, but `ctx` should be `message`. It doesn't matter much but it's a `discord.Message` object, not a `discord.ext.commands.Context` object.